# Can't convert types

Tags: javascript, automation, ios-ui-automation, javascript-automation

I am following the WWDC talk Javascript for automation. Following is an example from slide 99. 
I am getting an error on line 3 on new install of yosemite.

```
Safari = Application('Safari')
doc = Safari.document[0]
url = doc.url() // -> here
doc.url = 'http://apple.com'
```

Comment: In my case I was trying to access the properties directly rather than through getters. Use `Application('System Preferences').panes[0].id()
`

Answer (score 3):

The slide has a typo on  it. The second line should be

```
doc = Safari.documents[0]
                     ^
```

With document**s** (plural) instead of `document`.